# Is there any way to (temporarily) block an IP based on the requests it makes?

Tags: apache, security, drupal

Background: we're running Drupal 6 on an Apache server. I've scoured the internet but can't seem to find anything on exactly what I'm looking for, maybe someone here has an idea.

As a website with a decent amount of traffic, we tend to get a lot of low-level attack attempts. Any time I look through logs, there's at least a handful of "page not found" errors from script kiddies and bots trying to access pages like wp-login.php or admin.php. Obviously these attacks never get very far, but it's still a sometimes significant load on our server to serve up all the 404s.

These attempts are often quite amateurish. Generally, they all come from one IP address over a period of a few minutes. So I'm wondering if there's some way to implement temporary blocks by IP address for anyone who tries something that's obviously an attack. For example, maybe there's a way to configure .htaccess to say:

If (bot_IP tries to access wp_login.php, admin.php, administer/index.php, phpmyadmin.php and so on)
  Deny from bot_IP for next four hours

Has anyone ever tried anything like this? It would be wonderful if we could reduce the amount of time we spend sending 404s to attackers, and it seems to me like a lot of people could find it useful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you do this in a Drupal module, you'll spend more resources checking logs and filtering requests than you do sending 404's. If you have root access to the server, http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page will work very well. It scans the apache error logs, uses regex based rules to match log entries and updates the OS firewall rules to handle the blocking.